# flickering during reshaping

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am using FPSAnimator and jogl to draw rotating quad on GLCanvas. Normally graphics is not flickering and rotation is smooth, but when I resize window, or move it from nonvisible area of screen to visible area additional redraw requests are added. How can I filter out these additional requests as all drawing is done by FPSAnimator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try passing the parameter: `-Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true` to the JVM on the command line.  This should reduce/remove the flickering.

The problem is described on the [JoglUserGuide](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.1.0/jogl-1.1.0-windows-i586/Userguide.html)

Specifically:

> Another issue that occasionally arises on Windows is flickering during live resizing of a GLCanvas. This is caused by the AWT's repainting the background of the Canvas and can not be overridden on a per-Canvas basis, for example when subclassing Canvas into GLCanvas. The repainting of the background of Canvases on Windows can be disabled by specifying the system property -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true. Whether to specify this flag depends on the application and should not be done universally, but instead on a case-by-case basis. Some more detail is in the thread "TIP: JOGL + Swing flicker" in the JOGL forum.

Comment: that removed unnecessary background clearing, but to remove additional paint requests I had to put following code in paint method: if(first){first=false; super.paint(g)} else return; now super.paint is called only once, and it seems that all painting now done by FPSAnimator